# Multiple versions of Perl on Windows 7

Tags: windows, perl

This is my first day with Perl. I am confused with multiple versions of Perl on my system (Windows 7 32-bit). After installing [**DWIM Perl**](http://dwimperl.com/windows.html) when I checked for a Perl installation using 'perl -v' it was showing

```
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for msys-64int
```

and after setting the path of System Variables to the `E:\Dwimperl\perl\bin` directory it is showing

```
This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
```

Does Windows comes with Perl installed? And will overwriting `PATH` do any harm?

Comment: Please don't use **bold** except for occasional emphasis. Stack Overflow uses [*markdown*](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and you should familiarise yourself with it

Comment: It looks to me like the 5.8 version comes from a 64-bit version of Mingwin or Cygwin, while the 5.14 version is native Windows but limited to 32-bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- No, Windows doesn't have Perl installed by default. Someone before you has installed Perl 5.8.8
- You probably won't do any harm *adding* a location to the `PATH` environment variable, but your question isn't clear. Have you changed it to just `...\Dwimperl\perl\bin`, or have you added it to the end?

You really shouldn't use relative paths in the `PATH` list, if that is what you've done. Do you really have three dots in there? If so then I am surprised that it works at all.

I suggest you run `appwiz.cpl` and look to see what is installed there. Remove the older Perl if you are sure there is no need for it.

Also, I recommend that you use Strawberry Perl rather than the DWIM fork. The only real difference is that it has a lot of additional modules pre-installed that you may well not need, at the expense of being a couple of versions behind basic Strawberry Perl